# Laradock error on mysql_connect

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, laradock

I have a problem with mysqli and mysql. I'm using laradock on Mac, after the `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin` and try to open my PHP project on web, I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function `mysqli_connect()` in /var/www/f......
```

I read the php specs with `phpinfo()` but Mysql seems to be set correctly.

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve myself.
On .env file of Laradock I enabled MYSQL

```
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQLI=true
```

After in terminal I launched this command

```
docker-compose build php-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Install php5-mysql

```
 apt-get install php5-mysql
```

And also make sure that you removed ; in php.ini file for below extension. This file can be found in etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```